# В чем причина сообщения "Access denied for user"?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Сразу скажу, что новичок. Занимаюсь по книжке. Установил EasyPHP-3. Apache и MySQL работают нормально (зелёный индикатор). На диске С создал папку web, куда складываю примеры. Взял из книги короткую программку для создания таблицы. Когда запустил, то получил такое сообщение:

> `Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'Guest'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:webinstall_1.php on line 10`

Я так понимаю, что к MySQL доступ закрыт. Нужны какие-то дополнительные настройки. База данных и таблица не сформировались.

Answer (score 1):

Неверный логин или пароль. [Проверьте](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php), все ли правильно указали.

Answer (score 1):

В 10й строке скрипта по адресу C:webinstall_1.php есть у вас функция mysql_connect(). В ней указаны имя пользователя, пароль и база данных к которой производить подключение. Проверяйте правильность введённых данных.